# Getting until exception in FluentWait try every solution does not work please help

Tags: selenium, java

```
Wait<WebDriver> wait1 = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
                .withTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .pollingEvery(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);



        WebElement clickSeleniumLink = wait1.until(new Function<WebDriver, WebElement> ()
        {
            public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver){
                return driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id = 'java_technologies']/li[3]/a"));
            }   
        });
        clickSeleniumLink.click();
        driver.close();
        }
```

Comment: Hi Rmodi, would you care to share commentary on what's going on? What exception are you getting and on what line?

Answer (score 1):

Use this Generic function

```
public void FluentWait(String XpathKey) {
            try {
                FluentWait<WebDriver> fluentWait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
                        .withTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS).pollingEvery(3,
                                TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                fluentWait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By
                        .xpath(OR.getProperty(XpathKey))));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Fluent wait failed due to = " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
```